# How to display the body of the mail in another page if clicked on the subject

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I am creating an inbox in PHP and It displays Mail Id and Subject.
If you click that division(containing mail id and subject), it opens up a new page, read. PHP where the body and attachments are displayed.
I am facing some problem in getting to know which division is being clicked and how to display the mail of that particular person.

My concerned code is:

```
<?php
    $conn = connect(); //Connects to the database
    $sql = "select senderId, subject, body, attachment from mail where receiverId = '".$_SESSION["Email"]."' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='mail' onclick='location.href=`read.php`;'>";
        echo $row["senderId"] . " - " . $row["subject"];
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<hr />";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

I have an idea of storing the variables using SESSION as:

```
if (isset($_GET['div'])) {
            $_SESSION["body"] = $row["body"];
            $_SESSION["attachment"] = $row["attachment"];
        }
```

But where do I place the latter part of the code and suggest me if I can make an modifications please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `echo` out the id during the while loop iteration.

```
echo "<div class='mail' onclick='location.href=`read.php?id=". $row['id'] ."`;'>";
```

And inside the `read.php` file, you can then grab that value by using `$_GET['id']`.